# Using custom fonts

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

So I'm able to use custom fonts by adding them to my Xcode project and info.plist like so:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/load-and-access-custom-fonts.html

However, I tried adding another in the same way, but that UIFont doesn't seem to work for some reason. The UILabel just shows the default font setting. Is there a particular reason why one .ttf would work and another wouldn't?

Comment: A good reason would be that you mixed up the file name with the font-family name.

Comment: Once you added it, write `NSLog(@"Fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);` somewhere it will be executed, and it will display a list of the family names you can use. Sometimes a font family name is not the same as it's file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EmilioPelaez commented, font family names can sometimes be different from the file names. Using the NSLog technique `NSLog(@"Fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);` can help to find out what the family name of added fonts is.